# Materialized view concurrent refresh is taking significantly longer than non-concurrent

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a materialized view that aggregates 5 tables (that are out of my control) with some optimization running on Postgres DB. There is about 30-40 million rows per table. This materialized view needs to update once every day (after midnight) as new data gets added/updated in those 5 tables. there is about 50k-150k updated rows that needs to be refreshed in mat view every day.

Here is the problem, when I refresh the materialized view without concurrent it is done in about 25-35 mins. However, when doing it concurrently it is taking about 15+ hours! thats with indexes dropped. I wonder if that is to be expected and what should I be troubleshooting in this scenario? I set work_mem to 500MB in a 2GB RAM and IOPS is set 2000 on RDS.

If that is to be expected and can't be resolved I was thinking of creating two materialized views where I would route to one while the other is updating, is that a good idea or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

Another option might be to create a new materialized view without `CONCURRENTLY` and then replace the old materialized view with the new one, best in a transaction.

Then you can have “fast” materialized view building and still access the old version while you are building. The downside is that you will need more storage space.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour where the refresh may take longer with CONCURRENT is to be expected as the database is allowing the possiblity of allowing others to query the materialized view during the fresh. It usually runs faster without the concurrent (consider it a dedicated process) and uses less resources but prevents others from interacting with the view during the refresh. You may read more [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html).

It may be simpler to allow the downtime during the refresh. However, if querying the view during the refresh is important and you would not like to continue to use the built in functionality you could consider a more involved approach of creating indexes for partitions (say daily loads), manually doing inserts and ensuring your queries retrieve data based on the last available partition (eg WHERE CURRENT_DATE - integer '1'). This incremental load could be automated.